# How to instantiate class in one line code of function calling?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, instantiation

I am doing this code bellow, creating a class and send in the next line by parameter in two lines of code:

```
InternalMessage im(call.get_id(), CSEV_CALL_NEW);               
send_call_event(im);
```

I would like to do something like that using only one line, as C#:

```
send_call_event( new InternalMessage(call.get_id(), CSEV_CALL_NEW));
```

Any suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

```
send_call_event(InternalMessage(call.get_id(), CSEV_CALL_NEW));
```

Which will construct a temporary `InternalMessage` and pass it to `send_call_event()`.

Note that if the parameter is passed by non-const reference it won't work, then a named variable is needed.

Comment: It works, thanks, why I do not need use the operator new?

Comment: In c++, `new` will create a pointer, i.e. `InternalMessage*`, it seems doesn't match the parameter type of `send_call_event()`.